# If the U.S. government eliminates private health insurance, how would it deal with the shareholders of private insurance companies?

Tags: united-states, law

If the U.S. government eliminates private health insurance, how would it be going to deal with the shareholders of private insurance companies? Would it reach some form of deal and what kind of deal? What would the process involved in transitioning from the current system to a completely public healthcare system include?

Comment: Are you primarily interested in A) specific plans from politicians who are proposing these policies, B) historical examples of how this was dealt with in other countries when they implemented single-payer healthcare, and/or C) proposals from think-tanks or advocacy groups? Narrowing down the question may help you get better answers

Comment: I would say B).

Comment: Note that even in countries like the UK, where we have nationalised healthcare, private health insurance and healthcare still exists, for those willing to pay for it.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff  But this is in the US context, where the question is what will happen to the private health insurance companies if they are banned as first insurers, which is what the actual plan under discussion would do.  Whether or not that is the same as the UK system or not is irrelevant, as the US is not passing the UK system.  It's making its own and there is a current plan being discussed.  The US would still have supplemental insurance under most versions of the plan, but that seems a much smaller market than employer-based insurance.

Comment: @Brythan: thank you for the clarification. It might make things clearer (particularly for those not familiar with the proposal which inspired the question) if this was included in the question.

Comment: I find it completely unbelievable that the policy would proceed with banning all private medical insurance; note that e.g. non-citizens would still need it. I suspect this is a sacrificial policy that's being advocated to move the Overton window, and to provide advocates something to "compromise" over.

Comment: @pjc50 Compromise is something absolutely nobody in America is interested in at the moment.

Comment: What does your research show? How was distillers compensated when prohibition started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private health insurance is unlikely to be eliminated completely, but if the government provides free health to all it is likely that the number of people buying it would only be a few percent of what it is now.

Private insurance companies are private companies: the government doesn't owe them an existence. Therefore the simple answer is to let them shrink or go out of business.

In practice the US health sector is around 1/6 of the entire economy, and private insurance companies are a fair chunk of this. Hence the economic dislocation would be significant and mitigating its impacts will be something that the government would have to plan for in order to reduce the opposition to its changes.

Comment: @Trilarion Agreed.  Fixed.

Comment: In principle, the insurance companies could allege a regulatory taking in court. But I'm deeply skeptical of this argument actually working, for several reasons. I suppose you could also have litigation over whether operating a public health insurance program counts as "regulating interstate commerce," but lately the Supreme Court seems to think that power means whatever Congress says it means (see *Gonzales v. Raich*).

Comment: Do you have any sources to corroborate that it'd drop to a few percentage points?  A fair number of people get health insurance through work, and companies could still offer better/improved health insurance as one of the benefits. So I expect private insurers could retain most of that business.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I was thinking by analogy with the UK market, where the NHS provides care for everyone. Bear in mind that the US currently makes employer health insurance tax-deductible, which is why it is offered so universally in the US. In the UK it is a perk taxed in the normal way, so there is no advantage in doing it through the employer. If the US went for a single payer system the employer tax deduction would likely be abolished as well.